# Sharepoint Onenote Permissions Management

Tags: permissions

Is there a way to apply audience targeting in sharepoint to a OneNote Notebook? I also cannot find where the manage permissions feature is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do have the audience groups all set up you should just be able to enable audiences in the library where your OneNote notebook is. "Library settings" > "Enable Audience Targeting" > "Enable audience targeting" to get the column used for audience trimming.